# Logarithm computation (a fraction)

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I am trying to compute the following fraction but get failed as it leads me to log over log.

$$\frac{\log_{10}0.04-2\log_{10}0.3}{1-\log_{10}15}=2$$

Please help.

Comment: Please show your work so that we know exactly where and how to help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: You want to show that the equation holds? Are you familiar with the following rules of logarithms - $\displaystyle \log_a b-\log_a c=\log_a\left(\frac{b}{c}\right) \ , \ \log_a a=1 \ , \ n\log_a b=\log\left(b^n\right)$?

Comment: I just replaced $\log_{10}0.04$ by $\log_{10}4/100$ and 1 by $\log_{10}10$ then using log rule that change difference to quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac { \log _{ 10 } 0.04-2\log _{ 10 } 0.3 }{ 1-\log _{ 10 } 15 } &=&\frac { \log _{ 10\quad  }{ 0.04-\log _{ 10 }{ \quad 0.09\quad  }  }  }{ \log _{ 10 }{ 10 } -\log _{ 10 }{ 15 }  } \\
&=&\frac { \log _{ 10 }{ \left( \frac { 0.04 }{ 0.09 }  \right)  }  }{ \log _{ 10 }{ \left( \frac { 10 }{ 15 }  \right)  }  } \\
&=&\frac { \log _{ 10 }{ { \left( \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  }{ \log _{ 10 }{ \left( \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  \right)  }  } \\
&=&\frac { 2\log _{ 10 }{ { \left( \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  \right)  } }  }{ \log _{ 10 }{ \left( \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  \right)  }  } \\
&=& 2
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write the arguments as fractions and use $$\log \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)=\log(a)-\log(b)$$ and $$\log(a \cdot b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$ and $$n \log(a)=\log(a^n)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\log_{10}0.04-2\log_{10}0.3}{1-\log_{10}15}&=&\frac{\log_{10}4-2-2\log_{10}3+2}{1-\log_{10}5-\log_{10}3} \\
&=&\frac{\log_{10}4-2\log_{10}3}{1-1+\log_{10}2-\log_{10}3} \\
&=&\frac{2(\log_{10}2-\log_{10}3)}{\log_{10}2-\log_{10}3} \\
&=&2
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

Check that

$$\begin{align*}&\log 0.04=\log\frac4{100}=2\log 2-\log100\\
&\log0.3=\log\frac3{10}=\log3-\log10\\&\log15=\log3+\log5\end{align*}$$

Now put all this together carefully in the left side of your equality.

Answer (score 0):

$1 = \log_{10} 10$

So you get:

$\log (.04/.3^2)/\log 10/105 =$

$\log (4/9)/\log (2/3) =$

$2 \log(2/3)/\log (2/3) = 2$